# Sumproduct in excel using external data source

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate some data in a excel using external excel file. My formula is like;

**=SUMPRODUCT(--('[Stock Register.xlsx]Stock Code 1'!$E$3:$E$500="Issued to Sanitary Syndicate"),'[Stock Register.xlsx]Stock Code 1'!$C$3:$C$500)**

This works fine for me. But I need the sheet (Stock Code 1) being changed automatically when dragging or pasting on the next rows.

I am using it a new workbook using external data source (Stock Register.xlsx). Stock Register consisting of 570 sheets and for each sheets I need to display results in that New Workbook in cell (C1) using above formula and drag it to cell (C70).

Comment: To what will it be changed?  You will need to incorporate INDIRECT some how, but it depends on how the name will change.

Comment: You may have to use VBA for that! ;) But read the [tour] first! And [edit] your post to provide more details about which range you are trying to drag that formula on.

Comment: Please help....

Answer (score 0):

You can add two columns before the `SUMPRODUCT`.

First column, say this is in *column B*, will need to have `CONCATENATE` to the external spreadsheet that you want to link to.  For example:

`=CONCATENATE("[Stock Register.xlsx]Stock Code",ROW(A1),"!$E$3:$E$500")`

This should give you `[Stock Register.xlsx]Stock Code 1!$E$3:$E$500`.

Same thing for the second column that you want for `$C$3:$C$500` so you can get `[Stock Register.xlsx]Stock Code 1!$C$3:$C$500`.

Then the third column, say this is in *column D*, will be the `SUMPRODUCT` formula that with `INDIRECT`.  And here you go:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT(B1)="Issued to Sanitary Syndicate"),INDIRECT(C1))`

Hope this helps.

P.S. One thing I noticed when combining all three into one column, the formula wouldn't work.  Someone probably can come up a better way but to have a reference address sit next to the result may benefit you to debug down the road.  Just a thought.

---

UPDATED:
Okay, I was able to recreate what I described below. Maybe it is easier to show you in screenshots:

1. See I created three sheets in `Stock Register.xlsx` file, `Stock Code 1` sheet looks like below that values under `column C` and descriptions under `column E`.

   And another spreadsheet called `Results.xlsx`. `Column B` has a formula of `=CONCATENATE("'[Stock Register.xlsx]Stock Code ",ROW(A1),"'!$E$3:$E$500")`.

[image]

2. In this picture, `Stock Code 2` sheet looks like below.

   `Column C` in `Results.xlsx` spreadsheet has a formula of `=CONCATENATE("'[Stock Register.xlsx]Stock Code ",ROW(A1),"'!$C$3:$C$500")`.

[image]

3. In this picture, `Stock Code 3` sheet looks like below.

   `Column D` in `Results.xlsx` spreadsheet has a formula of `=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT(B1)="Issued to Sanitary Syndicate"),INDIRECT(C1))`.

[image]

Try again and let me know.

Comment: Not Working. Please Help

Comment: @arijitirf, check my updated answer and let me know if that works for you or not.

Comment: First I would like to give you a thank for spending time for me. Working only when the parent workbook is open. Is there any trick so that the formula can work without opening parent workbook. Thanks once again.

Comment: The short answer is NO if you need to link to a dynamic closed external file with `INDIRECT`. But you can Google for `INDIRECT.EXT` or `Harlan Grove's PULL` functions. Otherwise, you will need to write some VBA code (check out https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/14740-external-reference-using-vba.html#post68860 that can open the external spreadsheet silently) for it.